# How can I properly setup NextJS with Typescript, modules, and a custom server?

Tags: typescript, express, next.js

I just used `npx create-next-app --typescript` to setup a new NextJS app. This hooks TS to the app nicely. I want to use a custom express server at the same time. An [old article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/set-up-next-js-with-a-custom-express-server-typescript-9096d819da1c) I found seems too stale because it doesn't seem to know about this `--typescript` option when it describes how to set things up. I do have the customer server actually working "as expected" but it causes a TS script error and I can't use `import/export`.

[image]

Mind you I have only used the `create-next-app` command and created `server.ts` by copy pasting from [their code](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server).

My folder structure is:

```
- src
  - pages
    - api
      hello.ts
    index.tsx
  server.ts
```

If I use `import` I get this error:

```
(node:16882) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/dstein/Repositories/social-site/src/server.ts:1
import { createServer } = from 'http';
```

Comment: FYI `--typescript` option was added less than 2 weeks ago. So judging that article is old/stale because of the fact that it isn't using `--ts` or `--typescript` is not right. Also, you should have looked the official examples first. If they have some bug or don't work anymore (many of such are there because of new v11.0 release), create an issue on their GitHub. Here is probably what you are looking for: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/custom-server-typescript

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize it was so new.